# Failed on approval

Tags: ios, facebook, app-store

I submitted my app in appstore and i have this response From apple

> We found that your app exhibited one or more bugs, when reviewed on
>   iPhone 5 running iOS 6.1.4, on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks, which
>   is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> Specifically, we were not able to log in with Facebook.

But i tested the login facebook in my app in my iphone 4 (iOS 6.0.1) and it works.

What is the problem with facebook sdk in the ios 6.1.4

Please help.

Comment: Rather than assuming there is a problem with the SDK, have you run your app on 6.1.4 even on the simulator, as the error is in all likelihood in your own code? That should be your starting point.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem...I have come across same issue..!

Answer (score 0):

Try to install iOS 6.1.4 and run your app once. If facebook login is working, then you can contact Apple support team from the email you received after app fail.

Thanks
Jithen